# More than 2 months with status 'Editor assigned ' ; is it normal?

Tags: publications, journals, paper-submission, editors, withdraw

I'm a bit worried because my paper have been more than 2 months "with editor" status. It's a computer science journal , from a famous editorial. 
Normally we have the option to send an e-mail to the assigned editor, but in this case there is only "view your submission".

In this case, what should I do within the following choices?
1. Withdraw
2. Make direct contact to the editor
3. Just wait
4. Other

Also, if I should contact the editor directly, How can I know which editor to contact and how can I found his contact address ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: There are other q&a for this including : https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/16624/72855

Answer (score 1):

**Contact editor and ask for status update**.

Editor assigned generally means someone (whoever first received the submission) has chosen a member of the editorial board to handle the manuscript. It's because they haven't agreed to handle the manuscript that you don't have an assigned editor to email. It shouldn't take two months for the editorial board member to decide whether or not they can handle the manuscript, as well.

I would email the journal office or whoever you can contact and ask them what's going on. They might send a chaser to the invited editor, or they might invite a new editor; either way the ball's in their court.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I don't know which one I have to contact , the ditor in chief of the journal, the editorial ? I dont have any contact address

Comment: @AlizeC if you know how to contact the editor-in-chief, do that; otherwise you could look at the journal's website or the system used to handle the submission and see if there's a contact option.